# Centering a two column table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

I have the following page on a site:

[image: Screenshot]

I have centered those two columns by adding two columns around them with defined widths:

```
    <table class="form">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:20%;"></td>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" class="medium" value="" /></td>
    <td style="width:20%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <th>Password</th>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="medium" /></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <th><label for="remember">Remember my user ID</label></th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="true" /></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><a href="forgot/">Forgot your user ID or password?</a></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without the two empty columns on the side sized with a width of 20%?

Comment: OT: Please add `role="presentation"` to your `<table>` tag, so assistive technology doesn't treat it like a normal table, and `<tfoot>` isn't needed here, and used incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style>
table.form {
    width: 400px; /* or however wide you want it */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

You can then make the submit button span the entire width by putting it in its own element if you wish, or you can keep it in the table for a consistent width.

Comment: That works but also makes the tfoot where I have the buttons 400px which I need to have fill the app's container

Answer (score 5):

Although you can find a solution to get through with tables as someone has already solved, I would suggest you not to use them for this, tables are always problematic to style. You could have done this using different html elements such as divs. Just consider it next time :)

Comment: +1. This. Just to clarify: tables are for tabular data. Not layout. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm working with a CSS framework that someone else developed.  This is only for one screen so I was looking to avoid adding new styling for a single use.  Lazy for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Defining width of element you want to center (with pixels, em-s, percentages ..), and setting `margin-left: auto` `margin-right: auto` would help